# remove class when value is empty

Tags: jquery, string, if-statement

If my variable contains a value it adds a class to an element. However when the variable contains nothing it doesn't remove the class. Can somebody please tell me why?

```
var barrel_items = [];
var barrel = barrel_items;

if ( barrel ) {
    $('.send-order').addClass( "show");
} else if (!barrel) {
    $('.send-order').removeClass( "show");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)** property for array

```
var barrel_items = [];
var barrel = barrel_items;

if ( barrel.length ) {
    $('.send-order').addClass( "show");
} else {
    $('.send-order').removeClass( "show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `length` of the `array`, since empty array wont be a falsy one,

```
$('.send-order').toggleClass( "show", barrel.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the length of array elements. also you can use `.toggleClass()` instead of show/hide to achieve this:

```
var barrel_items = [];
var barrel = barrel_items;
$('.send-order').toggleClass("show",barrel.length != 0);
```